# MLE estimation: Inverse gamma duration model with exogenous variables

Tags: maximum-likelihood, survival, hazard, inverse-gamma-distribution

I observe a cross section of durations, $t_1, \ldots, t_n$ which are all strictly positive and a corresponding vector of exogenous variables $x_i$ which are assumed not to change from time $T=0$ until the "failure time" $T = t_i$. As explained for instance in [Green (Chapter 25)](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/product/Greene-Econometric-Analysis-7th-Edition/9780131395381.html) , making the hazard rate $\lambda = \lambda(x_i)$ a function of a set of regressors corresponds to accelerated failure time models.

I parametrize the duration $t_i$ using the inverse gamma distribution $IG(\alpha, \beta)$ and want to estimate the model using MLE, however I am not sure if my approach is correct:

1. Is the MLE approach below correct at all?
2. For the Weibull case or exponential models, one can derive analytical solutions for $E(t|x_i)$ or, similar, the conditional median can be obtained. For the inverse gamma case I assume one can work with $E(t|x_i) = \beta_i/(\alpha_i -1)$ which requires restrictions with respect to $\alpha_i (>1)$ for all $i$.

First, the (log-)Likelihood of the data is

$$\log\mathcal{L}(\alpha, \beta, t, x) =  \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_i\log\beta_i -\log(\Gamma(\alpha_i)) - \left( (\alpha_i - 1)\log(t_i) + \frac{\beta_i}{t_i}\right)$$

I parametrize the shape $\alpha_i > 0$ and scale $\beta_i > 0$ of the inverse gamma distribution as

$$\alpha_i = \exp(-x_i\gamma^\alpha)\\\beta_i = \exp(-x_i\gamma^\beta)$$

The set of parameters $\theta = [\gamma^\alpha, \gamma^\beta]$ is estimated using `optim` in `R`:

```
survival_regression <- function(tau, X){

  f.ig <- function(gamma, X, tau){
    # Log likelihood for set of parameters gamma    
    alpha <- exp(-X%*%gamma[1:ncol(X)])
    beta <- exp(-X%*%gamma[(1+ncol(X)):length(gamma)])
    logL <- sum(alpha*log(beta) - lgamma(alpha) - (alpha - 1) *log(tau)  -     beta/tau, na.omit=TRUE)
    return(-logL)
  }

  gamma.init <- rep(0, 2*ncol(X))
  fit <- optim(gamma.init, 
                 f.ig, 
                 X = X, 
                 tau = tau, 
                 hessian = TRUE, 
                 control = list(maxit = 10000))

  print(data.frame(Variable = colnames(X),
                   Value = fit$par, 
                   Std.Error = sqrt(diag(solve(fit$hessian))),
                   z = fit$par/sqrt(diag(solve(fit$hessian))),
                   p = 2*pnorm(-abs(fit$par/sqrt(diag(solve(fit$hessian)))))))
  return(fit)  

}

# Example

library(survival) # Example data set (lung)

sample_clean <- as.matrix(na.omit(lung))
tau <- sample_clean[, 2]
X <- sample_clean[, -(2:3)]
fit1 <- survival_regression(tau, X)
#     Just for comparison: exponential model from survreg package
fit_package <- survreg(Surv(time) ~ . -status , lung, dist="exponential") 
summary(fit_package)
```